# passing parameters after executing an exe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute an exe file through python. Once the exe is triggered successfully it displays few options like:

```
0 = Exit
1 = abc
2 = xyz
```

I want select one of the option from the console.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Start with checking out [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score -1):

Can use `sys.stdin` and `process_name.communicate(paramenter)` to read console input and pass it to the exe file process.

Comment: So far I tried 

import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('fortranExecutable', stdin=PIPE) #NOTE: no shell=True here
p.communicate(os.linesep(["1"]))

It is throwing an error typeerror str obj is not callable. :(

Comment: The obj not callable is because of os.linesep . os.linesep cannot be called as a function os.linesep(parameter), hence the error "not callable.

Comment: os.linesep returns '\r\n'

Comment: This seems to be working.. 

import os, subprocess

executable=("xyz.exe")
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, shell=True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(b'4')